# ASP.NET Maintaining ViewState for controls inside a custom control template

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, templates, custom-controls, itemplate

I have a template property in my control declared as follows:

```
<TemplateContainer(GetType(GenericTemplateContainer)),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
    TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)>
Property CustomTemplate As ITemplate
```

In my control's `Init` event I have the following:

```
If Me.CustomTemplate IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim TemplateContainer As New GenericTemplateContainer
    Me.CustomTemplate.InstantiateIn(TemplateContainer)

    PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(TemplateContainer)
End If
```

This allows me to place controls in markup inside my template, but on a post back the controls inside the template are not holding their ViewState.

I have tried adding `PersistChildren(True)` attribute to CustomTemplate property but I cannot because it's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the values into ViewState?  From what I understand, you need to do that.  Either that, or re-bind with the data on every postback.

Here's what I like to do inside User Controls.  I apologize for this being C# and not VB, but I don't know VB:

```
    public string Text {
            get { return (string)ViewState["Text"]; }
            set { ViewState["Text"] = value; }
    }
```

Reference:  https://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate

Comment: Thank for the answer, yes, I've tried ViewState but it didn't make a difference.